# PLW-06002 unreachable code when using NULL;

Tags: oracle, plsql

I occasionally do something like....

```
IF very-likely-condition THEN
    NULL;
ELSE
    <<code to deal with the unlikely condition>>
END IF;
```

Which gives a **PLW-06002 unreachable code** warning from the PL/SQL compiler on the NULL line atfer the IF.

Now whilst I can clearly ignore the warning and/or refactor the IF statement to be a NOT, I think it reads better this way.

So does anybody know is there is another way of inserting an empty statement so that I don't get the compiler warning?

**EDIT:**

I'm not saying I do this often... in fact I'd do it very rarely.  But occasionally I do think it reads better this way.

**EDIT 2:**

Plus there are other scenarios where it might be valid to do this (such as ignoring a specific error in an EXCEPTION block).  I only used the IF as a simple example to illustrate the point.

Comment: What pl/sql optimizer level are you using?   
(select name, value from v$parameter where name = 'plsql_optimize_level' to check)
Oracle is probably refactoring the code into the {NOT ...} format for you

Comment: Level 2.   That could well be it in the case of an IF, but I'd still like to know if there's a workaround for other cases (e.g. ignoring certain errors in an EXCEPTION block)

Comment: This has somewhat of a smell, but you could create a NOP procedure with the NULL and use that instead of NULL in parent code - that way you'll only see the warning when you create NOP - would give your PL/SQL sort of an assembly language feel :)

Comment: @dpbradley: the NOP procedure (that only does NULL) also raises the warning PLW-06002, it starts to feel like recursion =)

Comment: +1 for the interesting question. I often run into this when developing and I just need to add a stub or place holder. Will be interested to see what the answer is

Comment: @Vincent - you're right, but at least it isolates it the warning to one place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is by design. See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/controlstructures.htm#i5421

Example 4-23 Using NULL as a Placeholder When Creating a Subprogram

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ... AS
BEGIN  
  NULL; -- use NULL as placeholder, raises "unreachable code" if warnings enabled
END;
/
```

Answer (score 4):

To Recursive And Weblog :

the following statements are **NOT** equivalent:

```
IF :x = 0 THEN
   NULL;
ELSE
   do_something;
END IF;
```

and

```
IF NOT :x = 0 THEN
   do_something;
END IF;
```

If `:x` IS NULL the `do_something` procedure will be called **in the first case only**. This is because the expression `NULL = 0` is neither TRUE nor FALSE in Oracle, it is "unknown".

The correct way to re-write the first statement would be:

```
IF :x != 0 OR :x IS NULL THEN
   do_something;
END IF;
```

I can see why in some cases we could write things as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have an empty statement? That's a code smell. It's generally accepted that is it **not** easier to read with an empty `if` block.

Change your `if` condition to the opposite of what it currently is:

```
IF NOT very-likely-condition THEN
    <<code to deal with the unlikely condition>>
END IF;
```

If you need to do something when the condition is true, you can always add that block back in. Empty blocks separate the condition from the block that's executed when the condition is true. It also looks like you used to have code in the `if` section, then removed it but were too lazy to rewrite the `if` condition to remove the empty statement.

Subjectively, if I were reading your code and saw the empty `if` block, I'd think you didn't know what you were doing.

Comment: I already said in the question that I knew I could do a NOT.  I'm not saying that this is something I do often at all.... but in certain rare cases I do believe this is more readable.  Do you have an answer to the question?